# How to integrate liqpay into Android?

Tags: android

I find java sdk https://github.com/liqpay/sdk-java for integration liqpay with maven, but my project uses gradle. So I can't use this. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you posted link to java library, not android version. I think that this version should be used on server side, not client (android) side.
Here is link to right github project:
https://github.com/liqpay/sdk-aos
Here is additional link with description of library that was described in ugly way:
https://www.liqpay.ua/en/doc/aos/

Anyway, maybe you finished your task with LiqPay on android? If so, please, post complete solution of this task

Comment: Ok, I wrote my own sample project that uses LiqPay Android SDK. It is here: [LiqPaySamplePrj](https://github.com/VaDRo/LiqPaySamplePrj)